# PHP Multi-dimensional array rearranging

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array that i want to re-arrange

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [feeds_id] => 1338
            [flag] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [feeds_id] => 1339
            [flag] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [feeds_id] => 1339
            [flag] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to arrange it to look like this

```
[1338] => Array ( 
             [0] => 0
             ) 
[1339] => Array ( 
            [0] => 0 
            [1] => 1
           )
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I suggest you research on "converting stdClass into Array" on Google. When you find some problem while trying what you've learned, you come back here with a question.

Comment: `foreach ($array as $v) $result[$v->feeds_id][] = $v->flag;`

Comment: Yes i have tried the following so far $item_key="";
foreach($items as $item){
 $item_key[]=$item->feeds_id;
} this give me the following rray ( [1338] => 0 [1339] => 2 ) but I still cant get exactly what I want
 $mimi =array_flip($item_key);
 
 print_r($mimi);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($items as $item){
    if(!is_array($newArray[$item->feeds_id])){
        $newArray[$item->feeds_id]=array();
    }
    array_push($newArray[$item->feeds_id],$item->flag);
}
```

You should first create an empty array where the new data will be stored. Then, inside the foreach, you should use array_push, BUT if the sub-array in where you want to put the data is not an array, you should declare it first (that's why the "if" before the array_push)

Comment: `$newArray[$item->feeds_id][] = $item->flag` will do just fine and is a lot more concise. If anything you should be using `isset` instead of `is_array`, otherwise you'll get a lot of notices thrown in your face.

Comment: Thanks @sebastianbarria and deceze. This has actually worked as I wanted it to. I still don't understand why there was lots of need down grading this question so much.